# Custom form adding a commerce price field

Tags: 7, forms, commerce

I am creating a custom form using the [form api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7). I'd like to reuse the price field used by [commerce](https://drupal.org/project/commerce), but I don't know how to include their form type in my own form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Price field with Currency outside of commerce and ubercart](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38463/price-field-with-currency-outside-of-commerce-and-ubercart)

Comment: The question link in my opinion does not show me how to add it to a form using the form api.

Comment: There's no "currency" or "price" or "money" fieldtype in the form API in core.

Comment: I do have Drupal Commerce installed all ready. Is it simple to add the price field from that module to my form?

Comment: Yes I think it is just like any other field, but 'type' would be the type defined by Commerce Price instead of a core type. If you look at the code of the field in the Commerce module it should be the same as that.

Comment: If you want help troubleshooting that or anything, I'm in #drupal-support on IRC and can help there.

Comment: What this price field should look like? What it should do? And why don't you just "borrow" some code from Drupal Commerce, if that's exactly what you want? It's open licence as far as I know, so it's legal.

Comment: Did you get this sorted.  I'm looking into doing the same thing at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
$form['price'] = array(
  '#type' => 'commerce_price',
  '#title' => $this->t('Price'),
);
```